# List of symbols with glossaries - create headers and cluster the symbols by topics

Tags: glossaries

I wonder if it is possible to create a list of symbols that is clustered by topics, similar to the clustering "Roman symbols", "greek symbols". 
I would like to cluster the symbols like "topic1", "topic2" and so on because sometimes symbols appear in different topics and mean something different.
I am using `glossaries` and at the moment my I create my symbols like that:

```
\newglossaryentry{sigma}{
    name        = {$\sigma$} ,
    description = {standard deviation} ,
    type        = symbol
}
```

Comment: Change "type = symbol" to e.g. "type = symbolRoman" and then for each type define a \newglossary and then use \printglossary[title={Roman Symbols}, type = symbolRoman]

Comment: Could you make your code snippet a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) please? Add a glossary as it is now and enough glossary entries to for us to test and demonstrate that a solution works.